# Is there a generic approach to Generating Function of periodic sequences?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, generating-functions, periodic-functions

Recently I read on wiki (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence#Periodic_0.2C_1_sequences)): *"Any periodic sequence can be constructed by element-wise addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of periodic sequences consisting of zeros and ones."*

On the other hand it is commonly known that such a *"periodic sequences consisting of zeros and ones"* correspond to a class of *Generating Function* of the type:

$$G(x)=\frac{x^{\gamma-1}}{1-x^\gamma} \qquad(1)$$

while $\gamma$ denotes the period from a $1$ to the next $1$ in the sequence.

***Question:*** *is there a theory whether the above claim can be also applied to the Generating Functions of the sequences, in other words, is there a way to deduct the Generating function of any arbitrary periodic sequence from the above class of Generating functions $(1)$ (by addition, subtraction, multiplication and division or else)?*

Comment: For a sequence $a_0, a_1, \dots$ with period $T$, the first $T$ values namely $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{T-1})$ obviously determine the sequence, and can be arbitrary. So the generating function of the period sequence would be $(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots a_{T-1}x^{T-1})(1 + x^T + x^{2T} + \dots) = A(x) \frac{1}{1-x^T}$, where $A(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots a_{T-1}x^{T-1}$ is arbitrary (can be anything). I don't understand your equation (1), but in any case that's all there is to say AFAICT.